# How to apply this preloading screen in angular 4 app?

Tags: angular, css, preloading

I've been trying to apply this preloading screen in angular 4. Here is the code of my index.html

[Here](https://codepen.io/cjnucette/pen/ZaWjLR) is the link to the code pen of this css effect .

I don't want any other preloading screens . Please be specific why this is not working not even in a dummy project. I've tried some other css screens but they are also not working. I've suspected the problem is in keyframes , they work with only transform property of css.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test4preloadingscreen</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>
    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700');

*, *:after, *:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

app-root {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #262626;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #484848;
  font-family: roboto, Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 5em;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
  animation: loading 1.4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    color: #484848;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  90% {
    color: #484848;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  100% {
    color: #fff900;
    text-shadow: 0 0 7px #fff900, 0 0 50px #ff6c00;
  }
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: .6s;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: .8s;
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
li:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
li:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}
    </style>
    <ul>
  <li>L</li>
  <li>O</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>I</li>
  <li>N</li>
  <li>G</li>
</ul>

  </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and it's perfectly working. Please re-check code. There might be some break in CSS. If any break present in CSS then after the break other CSS won't work. Hope it will help you.

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700');

*, *:after, *:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

app-root {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #262626;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #484848;
  font-family: roboto, Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 5em;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
  animation: loading 1.4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    color: #484848;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  90% {
    color: #484848;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  100% {
    color: #fff900;
    text-shadow: 0 0 7px #fff900, 0 0 50px #ff6c00;
  }
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: .6s;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: .8s;
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
li:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
li:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
  <li>L</li>
  <li>O</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>I</li>
  <li>N</li>
  <li>G</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried this in angular 4 app or in static html page?

Comment: Yes @HarkamalSingh

Answer (score 0):

This component control the show/hide splash screen, the steps will occur like this:

1- the browser will download index.html file in your server, and after will search from files indicate by index.html like: "runtime.js, polyfills.js, main.js, vendor.js" with duration of 300 milliseconds (in my case);

2- After that files download the page will show the splash screen;

3- After all "angular resolver"  will make the requests to your server to get your data components;

4- After all images, medias, fonts will be download

5- After, when all download and load, the splash screen will be hide

```
 @Component({
   selector: 'sei',
   templateUrl: './sei.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./sei.component.css']
  })   
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   public showSplash: boolean = true; //Show or hide splash screen

   window.onload = (event) => {
     this.showSplash = false; //Trigger when everything load
   }
 }
```

But we have a problem here, because the "splash screen" only is visible when the angular files is downloaded (index.html, "runtime.js, polyfills.js, main.js, vendor.js") we need wait all this angular files to show the splash screen during app load all components, images, resolver, etc.

We want start "splash screen" when the browser get the first index.html file, at this moment we want start show the splash screen and skill the other angular files.

go to your index.html and below "app" tag you can create your  "splash screen", this will show at the moment your browser get angular main index.html file.

```
 ...
 <body>
   <app></app> //YOUR APP
   <div id="splashScreen">
     splash screen, loading angular, wait... 
   </div>
 </body>
 <style>
  .splashScreenFadeHide{
     opacity: 0; //turn transparent
     transition: opacity 1s linear; //after 1 second
   }
 </style>
 ...
```

and to hide the splash screen when every thing was load, you will make:

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   ngOnInit(): void {
     window.onload = (event) => { //triger when every thing is load (files, assets, components' resolver, etc)
     
    // All good so add clas "splashScreenFade" to hide the splash screen slowly 
    document.getElementById("splashScreen").classList.add("splashScreenFadeHide")
   }

    //we are listening the "splasn screen" turn transparent and after apply the "display = none"  
   document.getElementById("splashScreen").addEventListener('transitionend', (e) => {
     document.getElementById("splashScreen").style.display = 'none'
   })
  }
}
```

Now we have a splash screen since the first file is load by browser, and hide only when all files, images, resolver, etc is read.

Give me a like if this help you.